# Intershop: what is BasketTotalPriceMinusLimitedTenderGross

Tags: intershop

Couldn't find it in the docs.

`BasketTotalPriceMinusLimitedTenderGross`

Min stackoverflow word requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the terminology of the standard ISH product the limited tenders are the amounts paid (covered) by the gift cards and certificates or payment methods which are not "open tender". Hm... The rest is self explanatory. I'm not sure why these terms were adopted in the basket calculation.